# What is the best directive to allow insert only positive number and not allow to insert minus

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to allow only positive numbers and not allow the sign minus.

I tried in this way

```
   <input formControlName="order"
                            class="questionario-input-border form-control" min="0" type="number">
```

but I can insert the sign minus.

I also tried with this

```
onlyNumber(event) {
const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
this.notNumeric = false;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
  this.notNumeric = true;
  return false;
}
return true;
```

}

but I can't input by keypad numbers.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i restrict input field to accept just string inside in template approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508764/how-can-i-restrict-input-field-to-accept-just-string-inside-in-template-approach)

Comment: Its even easier for the reactive form approach. Check out form validation in angular: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do this

method 1: use regex

```
<input aria-label="text input " type="text" pattern="^[-+]?([0-9](\.[0-9]+)?|[0-4][0-9](\.[0-9]+)?|50(\.[0]+)?)$">
```

You can use Regex patterns

Here I have included a pattern which takes values from -50 to +50

method 2

add this to block other text

```
 oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/regex strings or non numbers/g, '').replace(/regex for negative numbers /g, '$1')"
```